# PL/SQL package automated testing

Tags: sql, unit-testing, plsql, jmeter, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to test private procedures/functions in given pl/sql package (oracle environment).

I need rather simple test (run procedure, check DB if row exist/or check return value) but in complex testing suite.

**Which tool / approach would you recommend me ? (It's not possible to use paid solution).**

I'm using **SQL developer** so option #1 is it's internal JUnit testing framework.

Other option is **utPLSQL**, to be more independent of SQL developer.

Third approach is complete different. 
I would use Apache **JMeter** to connect to DB a write tests in JMeter. 
I'm quite familiar with this tool. 
Downside is that it would be probably difficult/impossible for me to test private functions.

Your opinion ?

Comment: Did you try coding using BeanShell sampler, where you write Java code to achieve your task?

Comment: I've been using BeanShell sampler most of time in previous project because Java is my primary coding language.

Comment: Conceptually I think you should not want to test private procedures and functions in a package. The specification is the contract; you should test the contract. An implementer has the freedom to change private implementation, but not the contract (specification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get your *"simple test in complex test suite"*. However if your main testing scenario is:

1. Set up test data in database table(s)
2. Run a PL/SQL subprogram
3. Verify the subprogram modified data in database table(s) correctly

I have a good news for you - http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/ is a great tool for that kind of testing. I have used it in several occasions and I'm very happy with it.

Oh, and one [can't access](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS00901) the package's private subprograms. You can only access package's public interface (the specification).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it.